# Phone number appending some unknown digit when I am going to call a phone

Tags: android, phone-call

I am trying to call a phone number programatically, but number is appending some unknown digits like "2255" or "011". My phone number format is : (###) ###-####. I just dont know how to solve this issue, or may be I dont know phone number formatting, can anybody help me please.

Comment: Try to provide digits only. NO FORMATTING digits, nothing spurious - only numbers.

Comment: OK, yes you can use + as the international prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a call:

```
// Requires the CALL_PHONE permission (it really starts a call).
final Intent tnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
tnt.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Number));
tnt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(tnt);
```

OR (without starting the call)

```
/*
Doesn't require the CALL_PHONE permission.
It doesn't start the call, but brings you to the dialer window.
*/
final Intent tnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
tnt.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Number));
tnt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(tnt);
```

Number is a string like

```
String Number = "+493210210";
```

To filter a **dirty** number, use a filtering function, something like this:

```
private final String Filter(String Number)
{
    String result = Number;
    result = result.replace("#", "");
    result = result.replace("(", "");
    result = result.replace(")", "");
    result = result.replace("-", "");
    result = result.replace("*", "");
    result = result.replace(".", "");
    result = result.replace("/", "");
    result = result.replace("\", "");
    result = result.replace(" ", "");
    result = result.replace(" ", "");
    return result;
}
```

and use it like:

```
Number = filter(Number);
```

Comment: That is working I know, but what should I do if I am getting this kind of number format.

Comment: remove spurious charactes like "(", ")", "#", "-", ... i.e.: **Number = Number.replace("#", "");**. That is, make a "filter" function that return you a clean number

Comment: can you post some code, who can remove this multiple characters from my string.